# Как улучшить мой план по командной разработке в Git?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-branch

Всем добрый день!
Я с гитом плотно никогда не работал, особенно при командной разработке. Только сам в Github что-то пушил, комитил. У нас есть следующая задача:

1. Существует общий репозиторий с метаданными заданий, если проще, репозиторий с заданиями.
2. Есть несколько разработчиков, которые должны брать актуальную версию задания (из master), дорабатывать их.
3. После доработки, эти задания должны быть перенесены сначала в ветки dev и test. А после тестирования, через merge request gitlab в master.
4. При этом разработчики не должны каким-то образом конфликтовать друг с другом, затирать чужие задания.

Я накидал следующий процесс, оцените его пожалуйста, может можно как-то сделать лучше:

````
git checkout -b pogorelov_misrep630 master
Разработка ведётся локально в этой ветке. Локальное тестирование тоже.
После разработки, разработчик выполняет коммит изменений:
git add *
git commit -m “Добавил шаги 1 и 2”
Для тестирования на контуре DEV и TEST разработчик сначала выполняет pull репозитория, затем merge своей локальной ветки в нужную ветку контура (DEV, TEST) и push изменений в Gitlab.
    git pull
git checkout dev
git merge –no-ff  pogorelov_misrep630
git push
После успешного тестирования на DEV и TEST, разработчик делает push своей локальной ветки в удаленный репозиторий Gitlab .
    git push -u origin pogorelov_misrep630
Для внедрения в master разработчик создает Merge request в Gitlab, указывая свою ветку в Gitlab в качестве источника.```
````

Comment: То, что тут названо задачей, - это процесс, а то, что названо процессом - команды git.

Comment: я вижу одну большую проблему - если сами задания лежат в репозитории, то есть шанс, что разные разработчики возьмут одну и ту же задачу. Поэтому, скорее всего, вначале человек должен взять задачу и отредактировать файл/файлы с заданием (поментить как "взял" ) и тут же закоммитить в мастер.

Comment: @KoVadim я так понимаю, что под "не должны затирать чужие задания" имеется ввиду работа в изолированых ветках на задачу, а не то, что сам git используется для отслеживания задач. Если это так, то тут описан типичный [git flow](https://bit.ly/37TLiHG) с дополнительной веткой test (аналогичной develop).